# nodes created within the appendchild argument is not executing

Tags: javascript

I execute the following lines in Console

```
thead=document.createElement('thead')
thead.appendChild((document.createElement('th')).appendChild(document.createTextNode('Inner Text')))
```

But when I execute thead, the return is a 'thead' tag with 'Inner Text' as its content. There is no 'th' tag as per the command execution.

Why does it not work?

Comment: If you're doing this before `thead` is appended to the _#document_, don't worry as much about appending order because it won't be painted yet

Comment: Just remove the `(` before `createElement('th')`, and the `)` at the very end of the line. But why are you putting a `th` in a `thead` in the first place? It belongs in a `tr`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.appendChild()` returns the appended child:

```
var thead=document.createElement('thead');
var th = document.createElement('th');
th.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Inner Text'));
thead.appendChild(th);
```

If you want to do this in one line, you could call the `.parentNode` of the added node:

```
thead.appendChild(document.createElement('th').appendChild(document.createTextNode('Inner Text')).parentNode)
```

Comment: Your last line would be identical to the code in the question.

Comment: @cookiemonster No, it's not, check it in the end of line.

Comment: Sorry, the parens in the question look really messed up because of the extra `()` around `document.createElement("th")`. A cleaner solution would be `thead.appendChild(document.createElement('th')).appendChild(document.createTextNode('Inner Text'))` No need for `.parentNode`. Just need to correct the order that the question defined.

Answer (score 1):

`node.appendChild()` *returns* the appended element.

> The appendChild method returns a reference to added node.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild#Description)

You'd want to break it up something like this...

```
var thead = document.createElement('thead');
var th = document.createElement('th');
thead.appendChild(th);
th.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Inner Text')));
```

Comment: According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild , it does.

Comment: @FelixKling I wrote it wrong first, should be correct now.